# Intent does not start

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to select an image from the galley and then process it , i'm doing it by having pressing a button on the main activity , which then starts a new activity where you can select either a build in image or select your own , and when i want to choose my own image it should open the gallery and let me pick an image , how come this does not work somehow (although it did work before , i think i just broke something , but don't know what)

my code :

```
package il.popov.ecptest;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class select_activity extends ListActivity {

ListView listView;
Intent intent;


@
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    String[] StringArray = {
        "Select your own", "image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "None"
    };
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, StringArray));
    intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), main_activity.class);
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            processClick(position);
        }
    });
}



public void processClick(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            //startActivity(i);

            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 237);

            //Returns to main activity , DO NOT CHANGE
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 1:
            midClass.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
            midClass.isImageSelected = true;
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 2:
            midClass.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image2);
            midClass.isImageSelected = true;
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 3:
            midClass.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image3);
            midClass.isImageSelected = true;
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 4:
            midClass.img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image4);
            midClass.isImageSelected = true;
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 5:
            midClass.img = null;
            midClass.isImageSelected = false;
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            midClass.toastificate("Error in selection process");
            midClass.isImageSelected = false;
            midClass.img = null;
            break;

    }
}



@
Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    midClass.toastificate("checking result");
    if (requestCode == 237 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        midClass.toastificate("Processing image");
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inMutable = true;
        midClass.img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, opt);
        if (midClass.img != null) {
            midClass.isImageSelected = true;
        } else {
            midClass.isImageSelected = false;
        }

    }
}
}
```

I used the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: Why do you have two startActivity in case 0?

Comment: The first starts the gallery to select an image and the other returns to the main activity , i know there is a better way to do that , but that's not my problem right now

Comment: That's not what it does. It starts your gallery picker and also starts the main activity on top of that. So nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case 0:
        //Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        //startActivity(i);

        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 237);

        //Returns to main activity , DO NOT CHANGE
        startActivity(intent);// Remove this line  in your case 0
```

Comment: One of them starts the gallery and then return to the main activity , i know it can be done more efficently but that's not my problem right now

Comment: @DirtyAxe but no need to write startActivity(intent). when you select image then it is back to Activity